# how do i count Href using jquery

Tags: jquery, count, href

I want to count the Href in a page using Jquery .

Just for refrence:  i have random number of hyperlinks in a page for each user and all hrefs are diffrentiated with thier id eg. user_1,user_2,.... so here im  unable to call the function on onclick event using Jquery since each href is has different name and cannot also write separate jquery functions which varies for each user . so if i could get to count hrefs in a page i could easily call the function

waiting for reply

Thanks 
Mukesh

Comment: say what? I can't understand what you want to do at all here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the elements [`A`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-A), [`AREA`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-AREA), [`BASE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) and [`LINK`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK) can have a `href` attribute:

```
$('a[href], area[href], base[href], link[href]').size()
```

That will return the number of elements with a `href` attribute. The more specific the question, the more specific the answers.

Comment: ...or you can use `$('[href]').size()` to match everything with a href-attribute.

Comment: Note: This method has been removed in jQuery 3.0. Use the .length property instead.

Answer (score 3):

$('[href]').length ? (84 in this page right now, 88 when my comment wil be on it ? :p)

Answer (score 1):

i am not a js/jquery expert .. but should u be able to get back an array of "a" tags with

$("a") ?

Comment: It would be worth qualifying the selector with `a[href]` to differentiate between hyperlinks and named anchors.

Comment: @Alex: that is true, but you shouldn't be using the `<a>` tag for names anchors, you should use the `id` attribute.